# applying a function groupwise in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How would you apply a function groupwise to a pandas data frame; where the function is applied to the Child Group but the child groups are repeated across different parent groups?

Example:

```
| Parent Group | Child Group | Value |
--------------------------------------
|  A           | I1          | V1 |
-----------------------------------
|  A           | I1          | V2 |
-----------------------------------
|  A           | I2          | V3 |
-----------------------------------
|  A           | I2          | V4 |
-----------------------------------
|  B           | I1          | V5 |
-----------------------------------
|  B           | I1          | V6 |
-----------------------------------
|  B           | I2          | V7 |
-----------------------------------
|  B           | I2          | V8 |
-----------------------------------
```

Expected output:

```
| Parent Group | Child Group | Value     |
------------------------------------------
|  A           | I1          | f(V1, V2) |
------------------------------------------
|  A           | I2          | f(V3, V4) |
------------------------------------------
|  B           | I1          | f(V5, V6) |
------------------------------------------
|  B           | I2          | f(V7, V8) |
------------------------------------------
```

I could make the Child Groups unique by combining the Parent Group key with the Child Group key e.g. ['A_I1', 'A_I2'] and then apply the function:

```
df.groupby('Unique Child Group').apply(f)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Parent Group', 'Child Group']).apply(f)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something like this:

```
df.groupby(['Parent Group', 'Child Group'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Output:

```
              Parent Group  Child Group
A             I1             V1, V2
              I2             V3, V4
B             I1             V5, V6
              I2             V7, V8
```

If you want to use any string formatting to change the output values you can do it this way:

```
df.groupby(['Parent Group', 'Child Group'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: "f(%s)" % ', '.join(x))
```

Output:

```
              Parent Group  Child Group
A             I1             f(V1, V2)
              I2             f(V3, V4)
B             I1             f(V5, V6)
              I2             f(V7, V8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: There are always 2 rows for each group.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Child Group': {0: 'I1', 1: 'I1',  2: 'I2',  3: 'I2',  4: 'I1',  5: 'I1',  6: 'I2',  7: 'I2'}, 'Parent Group': {0: 'A',  1: 'A',  2: 'A',  3: 'A',  4: 'B',  5: 'B',  6: 'B',  7: 'B'}, 'Value': {0: 'V1', 1: 'V2',  2: 'V3',  3: 'V4',  4: 'V5',  5: 'V6',  6: 'V7',  7: 'V8'}})

Out[1305]: 
  Child Group Parent Group Value
0          I1            A    V1
1          I1            A    V2
2          I2            A    V3
3          I2            A    V4
4          I1            B    V5
5          I1            B    V6
6          I2            B    V7
7          I2            B    V8
```

**Demo**

```
def func(x,y):
    return x+y

#group by Parent Group and Child group, the first value can be reference by x.iloc[0]['Value'] 
#and the second value can be referenced by x.iloc[-1]['Value']. 
#Below is an example to call a function to concatenate the two values.
df.groupby(['Parent Group','Child Group']).apply(lambda x: func(x.iloc[0]['Value'],x.iloc[-1]['Value']))
Out[1304]: 
Parent Group  Child Group
A             I1             V1V2
              I2             V3V4
B             I1             V5V6
              I2             V7V8
```